# If I have more than 10000 records stored in Elasticsearch, does a sorted query only sort from the first 1000 records, or all of the records?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I currently have about 18,000 records stored in elasticsearch, and I'm sending a query much like this example:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "sort": [
    {
      "created_at": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*rob*",
      "fields": [
        "name.firstName"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So my question is about the `sort` part of the query. I'm only asking for 100 records back, but will elastic search run this sort on all of the data (all 18,000 records) or will it only run on the first 10,000 records?

Comment: Can't you tell this from the 100 values you are getting back?

Answer (score 1):

It will sort all 18,000 documents by created_at and return top 100 of them